# JMES Expression To Extract and Concatenate Strings inside an array

Tags: json, jmespath

Given this Json here

```
{
  "locations": {
     "name": "Seattle",
     "city": "SanFrancisco",
     "town": "SantaBarbara"
  }
}
```

I would need to obtain an array of strings like this with JMES Path

```
[
  "name=Seattle",
  "city=SanFrancisco",
  "town=SantaBarbara"
]
```

Is it possible using Jmes Path? Because if i start the expression like this it seems I always loose the key associated with my value

```
locations.*
```

And i obtain like this

```
[
  "Seattle",
  "San Francisco",
  "Santa Barbara"
]
```

Comment: Nope, sadly, using `*` loses the keys as you stated and using `keys(locations)` does the opposite and loses the values.

Comment: is it not possible to combine 2 queries to obtain1 output?

Answer (score 1):

You can *map* the filter *join* if you create the array of arrays

```
[[`name`, name],
 [`city`, city],
 [`town`, town]]|map(&join(`=`, @), @)
```

Comment: This is a valid solution but unfortunately only works if you can predict the name of the keys you are going to process